# looking for cotton paper texture

Tags: graphics, photoshop

I would like to find a nice white cotton paper texture, which is very common in printwork, but seems really difficult to find online. this will be for commercial work.

Comment: Looks like this was [cross-posted to graphicdesign.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6866/looking-for-a-white-cotton-paper-texture), where it IMO fits better than here.  Migrate and merge?

Comment: yeah, that's fine. sorry. I usually post on stackoverflow. not as familiar with the other se sites.

Answer (score 1):

Google [web background "cotton paper" texture](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=web%20background%20cotton%20paper%20texture#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&q=web%20background%20%22cotton%20paper%22%20texture&oq=web%20background%20%22cotton%20paper%22%20texture&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...17896l20957l0l21350l2l2l0l0l0l0l37l71l2l2l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=ee620c53dd5739b4&biw=1600&bih=732)

[image: Cotton Paper Texture]

Comment: I know how to use google.....thanks. however, I said white cotton paper, and that's not very white, plus it looks like it goes to a flickr account with this, and I asked for commercial. "You have permission to use these textures freely when you incorporate them into yournon-profit artwork, please be sure to follow the terms below:"

Comment: @Timmerz the point is there are millions out there and most are easily adjusted with photoshop to match the tone you need, any stock photography site should suffice.

Comment: can you please show me the millions? which stock photography site? you did a quick search and obviously didn't pay much attention to my request. that's not very helpful to do that and then talk in vague general terms like millions, any...

Comment: @Timmerz have a look through that google search, there are quite a few commercial sites - notice I used "" to require the phrase cotton paper?...

Answer (score 0):

I use the copyright-free pictures site http://www.sxc.hu/ . It's pretty good.Also here's my favorite textures site: http://cgtextures.com/